# Target certain environments based on console input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg

To preface the question I am using an ejected `create-react-app` for the layout of my project.

I have 5 environments that my application is going to be deployed to. Each environment has the same set of services (mostly), for example one might look like:

```
//environment 1
https://environment1.service1.foo.bar
https://environment1.service2.foo.bar

//environment 2
https://environment2.service1.foo.bar
https://environment2.service2.foo.bar
```

To achieve this on past projects (Angular/Gulp) I had a gulp task that essentially would look for a variable being passed in

```
gulp build --environment environment1
```

The code to do so looks like this:

```
gulp.task('environment', ['clean-environment'], function() {
  log('Copying environment');
  var environmentFile = config.environmentSrcDir + 'env2.js';
  if (args.environment !== 'env2' ||
    args.environment === 'env3' ||
    args.environment === 'env4' ||
    args.environment === 'evn5') {
    environmentFile = config.environmentSrcDir + args.environment + '.js';
  }
  return gulp
    .src(environmentFile)
    .pipe(rename(config.environmentService))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.root));
});
```

And basically point to the correct file with the correct endpoints inside of it as well as other pertinent variables associated with that environment.

My question is, where given the fact that I am using `create-react-app` as a starting point, so webpack, and node scripts, how would I accomplish something like this. Basically I want to be able to say `yarn build env1` and then the project to set a constant or file of constants as the 'active` constants so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using "Create-react-app" then you have the ability to define development environment variable through different .env files.

Link: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

> .env:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = XXX-YYY-ZZZ.apps.googleusercontent.com
REACT_APP_API_PROTOCOL = http:
REACT_APP_API_HOST = localhost:3000
NODE_PATH = src/scripts
PORT = 9001
```

> .env.production:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = ZZZ-YYY-XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
REACT_APP_API_PROTOCOL = https:
REACT_APP_API_HOST = api.my-applicaton.com
NODE_PATH = src/scripts
```

> Read different .env configs according to current command (start / test / build). dev.env for start and test. prod.env for build. If custom config does not exist — read env variables from .env file.
>   Blockquote

You will tell which .env file will be used with your start project command.

You should have something like this in your `package.json` file under scripts object:
`"start-js": "react-scripts start",
 "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
 "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",`

Then you can start your project using specified commands. From the documentation, files on the left have more priority than files on the right:

`npm start: .env.development.local, .env.development, .env.local, .env
npm run build: .env.production.local, .env.production, .env.local, .env
npm test: .env.test.local, .env.test, .env (note .env.local is missing)`

For example, if you start with `npm run build`, you will be able to access variables defined in `.env.production` file.

In JavaScript code, you can use process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST.

Also, see this link on medium.com: https://medium.com/@tuchk4/why-i-love-create-react-app-e63b1be689a3

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense. So my real concern is that I want to say something like `yarn build production` and target that environment. My api calls include the environment in them (not `production.blah.com`, but think `east.myapp.com/service`) and whatever the environment is, all of the api calls need to include that environments specific string in the url. So how would I get that to proliferate through the app to a place where I could stub out the base uri's for the service calls?

Comment: You can create different `.env` files, with a definition for every environment. Then create config file where you can store alias for your .env variables, and then use it in your services.

Depending on your npm start/test/build command, different .env file will be created, and you will be able to access variables that you are declared.

Comment: I am still having some trouble targeting the specific files @TariqN. I understand the fact that you need to create different `.env` files each with the pertinent variables. But how then do I get one of those as the .env file of choice at 'build' time, or at 'start' time? I fail to see that in the tutorial you posted.

Comment: Please look at the edited answer, and let me know if you have any troubles.